# How to hide one of the radio button. React

Tags: reactjs

Below is my Code

```
<Field
  component={RadioValidateField}
  validate={[required]}
  required={true}
  options={[
    { title: 'Option1', value: 'Option1' },
    { title: 'Option2', value: 'Option2'}
  ]}
/>
```

I want to hide Option2.

Comment: Have you tried `disabled: true`?

Comment: Well i have tried  { title: 'Option2', value: 'Option2', disabled: true} still cannot

Comment: If you want to 'hide' it, just don't include in the options then..?

Comment: is this material ui component ?

Comment: @b3hr4d I believe that it is redux-form

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it before;

```
const options = [
    { title: 'Option1', value: 'Option1' },
    { title: 'Option2', value: 'Option2' }
  ];

options.splice(/* from index= */ 1, /* count */ 1); // remove option;

return (
. . .
<Field
  component={RadioValidateField}
  validate={[required]}
  required={true}
  options={options}
/>
. . .
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this really works, but it just remove Option2 and this have effected my other code.
The reason i want to hide it, is to prevent some of the user choose it. Only some user able to choose Option2

Comment: You can work with copy :  `const optionsCopy = [...options]`